# Asynchronous download of multiple images

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am new to ios app development.could you please tell me how to download two or more images asynchronously using NSURLconnection. I can do it for one one image but seeks some help to do it for two or more images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this I usually have a helper class which downloads an image given a URL that calls me back when it's done. I've actually released that code as part of my MJGFoundation project. Take a look at the class called [MJGImageLoader](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Utilities/MJGImageLoader.h).

Essentially it's very straight forward and what I do is wrap all the `NSURLConnection` handling into a single class which you then start by passing a block which will be run on completion. I suggest you either take my code there and use it or look at how I've done it and replicate it yourself according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

create a separate class lets say - `ConnectionManager` having `NSURLconnection` complete implementation. create a protocol in the same class.

in the controller, make object of `ConnectionManager` pass `delegate` as `self` and start downloading one file. on completion, `ConnectionManager` can trigger your delegate and can deliver you the downloaded data.

to download multiple files simultaneously, you need to make multiple objects of `ConnectionManager` and start your requests. With that you will also require to handle the delegate as to recognize, which request is triggering your `delegate`.

hope it'll help somewhat.